# Information disclosure via ktpass tool

Tags: windows, key-management

The Microsoft ktpass tool can be used to generate a .keytab file that contains a secret key. I'd like to understand the output of the tool.

An example output can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tsec/task_GeneratingtheKeytabFileandMappingtheServicePrincipalName-8371d4.html). I'm interested in the following part:

```
keylength 16 (0xdd74540caa4a230af2ed75558a37995d)
```

The [Microsoft documentation](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ktpass) is quite vague on the exact meaning of this output. Is this the actual key that has been generated? What would an attacker be able to do with this information?

Comment: Given that it says keylength 16 and then prints 16 bytes (128 bits), this seems like it is just the key.

Comment: Your question is basically "what is `0xdd74540caa4a230af2ed75558a37995d` in the output of this Windows command?" That makes it more of a Windows question, and although you ar worried about potential info disclosure, you have not confirmed there is anything to worry about. Have you run the command and compared the file contents to the stdout output?

Comment: This value was encountered during a pentest and I'm investigating the impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact the final derived key.

It's not particularly leaky in this context because as the caller you already have access to the raw secret (you need the password to generate the file), as well as once all is said and done you have the file itself which contains the keys in cleartext.

Of course if someone is taking the output of the tool and logging it somewhere broadly readable, well, that's certainly bad.